# Need help to find the inverse of a mapping implicitly

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $f: \mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ be the linear mapping which reflects $x$ over the plane $x1+x2+x3=0$. You are given that the standard matrix for $f$ is:

$$[f]=\frac13\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&-2&-2\\-2&1&-2\\-2&-2&1\end{array}\right]$$

**without using the row reduction technique** for finding inverses, determine $[f]^{-1}$ and explain how you obtained your answer

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format your questions.

Comment: Think about this geometrically, how could you "undo" a reflection?

Comment: Ahh, by reflecting it back again!

Comment: Yep.  Good job! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a reflection is its own inverse. Sure enough, it turns out $[f]\circ [f] = I$, and therefore $[f]^{-1}=[f]$.

No row reduction as required :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It all makes sense geometrically too :)